# inserting phone number in mysql isnt working

Tags: mysql

i have a table in mysql to register the event coordinators (for a fest) as:

```
CREATE TABLE `coordinators` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY COMMENT  'coordinator-id',
`eventid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT  'event-id for which coordinating',
`name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'name of coordinator',
`phone` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'event coordinators phone number',
`email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'event coordinator email-id',
INDEX (  `eventid`, `name`, `phone`, `email` )
) ENGINE = INNODB COMMENT =  'stores event coordinator details'
```

whenever i run a query:

```
INSERT INTO `coordinators` (eventid, name, phone, email) 
VALUES('1', 'abcdef', '8285066537', 'abcdef@xyz.com')
```

whatever phone number i try, if it is >=9 in length, mysql changes it to `4294967295`!!

please help!

Comment: ohh!! got it.. datatype of phone has to be `BIGINT` as maximum sixe of UNSIGNED INT is `4294967295` ! :P

Comment: Did you try increasing the number on your INT data type? ie. INT(15) or something?

Comment: yes.. i changed it to 20 but still didnt work..

Comment: Your `phone` really should be a `varchar`, not a number.

Comment: @mu: if we are not including '-' or '+' in our phone numbers then also is `varchar` recommended?

Comment: As phone numbers are not subjects of mathematical operations, I would agree varchar is more appropriate.  After all, as a string, you'd be able to do things like area-code or exchange searches...though for these types, youd might even consider splitting area code and the remainder.

Comment: Because a phone number is not a number, it is a code that happens to (usually) be made up of numeric characters. Sometimes phone numbers include extensions, country-specific formatting, some places like to spell out their numbers, etc. The same applies to zip codes, SSNs, and other things that look sort of like numbers, they're not numbers, they're strings that (mostly) contain numeric characters.

Comment: @mu '&&' hexparrot: okay. i'll do that. thanx!

Comment: Also, changing the "size" of an INT does not affect the number range it can store - it only affects the display width.  INTs, BIGINTS etc will always have ranges defined by the mysql field types.  See here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing phone numbers in numeric fields is never going to work.  You're never going to be able to store the leading zero for example, or other chars like braces or plus symbols which are commonly used to indicate area codes and country codes.

Phone numbers should always be stored as a varchar.

Comment: I agree, although *"is never going to work."* is very strong (Facebook is worth billions of dollars and they store phone as numbers :) A very bad choice but I guess it's now very hard to change it.

Comment: Agreed - but the big boys can still make mistakes .. if they need some assistance in designing facebook2 maybe they should call us :)

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using datatype `int` for phone number which have maximum value of 2^32 - 1 (`2147483647`) or  `4294967295` if unsigned . You should use datatype `varchar` for phone number.

Answer (score 0):

As `phone` is defined as `phone INT(10)`, Integer can't be put in codes. The mistake was that you was putting phone in quotes `'8285066537'`.

Also you have `eventid` in quotes in your query (`eventid` is defined as `eventid INT`.

Your query should be

```
INSERT INTO `coordinators` (eventid, name, phone, email) 
VALUES (1, 'abcdef', 8285066537, 'abcdef@xyz.com')
```

### Update 1

Regarding `4294967295`, you will have to define phone to [BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) as maximum range of INT is `4294967295`. Hence your number `8285066537` is rounding to `4294967295`.

Let me know if you have any problem now.

Comment: no. its still getting down to `4294967295`. i guess it is because of the size limit of UNSIGNED INT.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't noticed that... You will have to change your datatype for `phone INT(10)` to `phone BIGINT`... See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) for more details... Also read [this, its interesting](http://laughingmeme.org/2010/01/24/4294967295-and-mysql-int20-syntax-blows/)